# How to use Javascript to restrict browsers to create singular child window

Tags: javascript

Is there any JavaScript syntax to make sure, across prevalent browsers, merely single child window will be created when users click buttons or hyperlinks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just always use the same [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) whether it's a link or a window.open call.

```
<a href="foo.html" target="child">foo</a>

window.open("bar.html", "child");
```

Answer (score 1):

In which context are you talking about. Checking whether a tab of a certain kind is already open is not possible because it imposes security risks.

However, if you are suggesting to only have one window opened as Invoked by:

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, strWindowFeatures)
```

Then you will only be able to have one window open at any time with a specified **strWindowName**.

Comment: He never said he wanted to check whether a window was open.

Comment: Yeah but the checking mechanism would be implied to restrict only one window from being open at any one time.

Comment: @Ze, actually, the browser takes care of it as long as you use a consistent target.

Comment: Oh I see, well I knew that was the case when you use the window.open method. I must have thought it was the strWindowName that determined whether another window is opened.